# Exiting full screen does not re-render graph to same size in highcharts exporting at angular 7

Tags: highcharts, angular-material, export, angular7, fullscreen

Exporting button in highcharts is working properly. It's showing all options but on clicking on "View in full screen"  graph is not showing the full screen and while exiting also not rendering to original size.
I'm using Angular 7, Bootstrap 4, Material design and Highcharts 6.2.6. I've fixed height and width as I'm using the same graphs for multiple locations.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no Highchart 6.2.6 version - see: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/
2. The first fullscreen version was added to version 7.1.0, but the final/full version of this functionality is available from version 8.0.1 - you can find that information also here: https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/